# What could go wrong in this MySQL procedure?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have created procedure in MySQL to maintain stock. Here how it works if user want to maintain stock closing and sold is updated else only sold is updated, This is MySQL Procedure for maintaining stock, which does not worked, returned 0 rows affected, I have checked all data is available in tables for this to work but still not working:

```
BEGIN
WHILE (qqty > 0) DO 

IF (maintainStock = 1) THEN
    SET @date1 = (SELECT MIN(expiry_date) FROM `stock_current` WHERE closing > 0);
    UPDATE `stock_current` SET sold = sold + 1, closing = closing - 1 WHERE item_id = iid AND expiry_date = @date1;
    SET qqty = qqty - 1;

ELSE
    SET @date2 = (SELECT MIN(expiry_date) FROM `stock_current`);
    UPDATE `stock_current` SET sold = sold + 1 WHERE item_id = iid AND expiry_date = @date2;
    SET qqty = qqty - 1;

END IF;
END WHILE;
END
```

Comment: add more details pls, `qqty` and `maintainStock` are defined, or are they parameters?

Comment: They are the parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems with the code:

1. You are mixing user defined session variables with stored procedures. This may lead to side effects, since these variables can be modified by any code within the session. You shoukd declare your variables within the stored proc without `@`.
2. `@q` variable is not set anywhere. This means that the `if` never gets executed or you get an infinite loop. I do not even get why you have a loop in your code.
3. The two date variables are set to minimum dates across the table. However, in the `update` statement you use them in conjunction with `itemid` in the `where` clause. You cannot be sure that the minimum dates - `itemid` pairs do exist.
4. You did not include the definition of the stored proc, so I cannot comment on the parameters.

Comment: Thank You that helped alot.